# Unexpected token (9:13) error when trying to launch react app in terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am newer to the scene and I am currently working on converting my website to a mobile app using React Native and I am coming across this error. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it! :)

Here is the error I am getting:

```
iOS Bundling failed 790ms
SyntaxError: /Users/jj/nurse-job/App.js: 
Unexpected token (9:13)



7 |             <WebView
8 |                 source={{ url: { 
https://www.praecuro.com }}}
9 |     style = {{ marginTop: 20 }}
 |              ^
10 | />
11 |     );
12 |   }
```

Here is the full code in app.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native- 
webview"; export default class App extends 
React.Component {
render() {``
    return 
        <WebView
            source={{ url: { 
https://www.praecuro.com }}}
style = {{ marginTop: 20 }}
/>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in react native but Your URL is supposed to be a `string`?. Take a look at the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/webview)

```
 <WebView
   source={{
          uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'
        }}
style = {{ marginTop: 20 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting your url incorrectly. Inside the `{{` it is a json literal and you should use '' to set the value.

```
source={{ url: 'https://www.praecuro.com' }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am still getting the same error for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://www.praecuro.com" }}
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
      />
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing `{}` within the `url` will solve the issue, also use your `WebView` inside a `<View></View>`. And in the Usage guide of [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview#usage) it says to the in `source` prop you've to use **uri** not **url**.

Also, make sure your code doesn't have extra spacing in your code between package name or anything.

Your code should look like this:

```js
import React from "react";                       //this
import { View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview"; 
class App extends React.Component {    //Mention your class like this
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <WebView
            source = {{ uri: "https://www.praecuro.com" }}
            style = {{ marginTop: 20 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default App;                 //Then export it separately
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried adding this and got this error.

Unterminated string constant. (2:24)

  1 | import * as React from 'react';
> 2 | import { WebView } from "react-native- 
    |                         ^
  3 | webview"; 
  4 | export default class App extends React.Component {
  5 | render() {

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same code as i mentioned? i just updated my answer. There may be spacing issues.

Comment: It looks like the code may work but now I am getting a separate error.

react-native-webview could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../node_modules

Comment: make sure if react-native-webview is in your `node_modules` and also mentioned in `package.json` dependencies. try to install it again if its not there or link it. Also you can do run `npm install` again

Comment: Thank you was able to get past that now I have this.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by App)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in DevAppContainer (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot in your question, what;s the error you're getting

Comment: https://ibb.co/pWWZTvW
https://ibb.co/H73gNKP

Comment: There may be a problem with importing your `React` and exporting your `App` component. I just updated my answer

Comment: Thank you I tried but getting same errors. I will try to figure it out as I do not want to take all of your time lol. Thank you for your help!